# xcode: Creating a zoomable image with buttons inside

Tags: xcode, image, button, zooming

Hello and first of all a happy new year to everyone!!
I'm new to Stack Overflow but I used it often to get answers to my questions. But now I'm standing at the wall with no idea to get further on.

What I want to do: xcode - iPad Project

1. App is having a very big picture (4000px to 5000px)
2. App should start with picture scaled down to see the whole image
3. Picture should be zoomable and dragable
4. If picture is zoomed out you should have several buttons or selectable areas (invisible buttons) to display (pop up) a textfield. These buttons should also be zoomed wihtin the image. So

Example: Picture of a face

- Face is zoomed out and so the eye fills the whole display
- User touches the eyebrow
- A pop up is shown with a table "The eyebrow protects the eye from dust"

Point 1 and 2(and 3) I was able to set up with the tutorial from this Site: http://vimeo.com/1642150

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook up the delegate method for the UIScrollView.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   if (scrollView.zoomScale > EXTRA_INFO_THRESHOLD)
   {
      [self displayExtraInfoLayer];
   }
   else
   {
      [self hideExtraInfoLayer];
   }
}
```

Id guess you could dump those buttons into a UIView container and add that to the view hierachy in `displayExtraInfoLayer` above the scrollview.